# Is this metric space complete?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $a$, $b$ be two real numbers such that $a<b$, and let $X$ be the set of all (real or complex-valued) functions defined and continuous on $[a,b]$ with the metric $d$ defined as follows: 
$$ d(x,y) := \int_a^b \lvert x(t) - y(t) \rvert \, dt $$ for all $x$, $y$ in $X$.

Then I can show that $d$ is indeed a metric on $X$ and hence $(X,d)$ a metric space.

Now is this space complete? If so, how to prove this?

If not, then how to find a Cauchy sequence that doesn't converge in this space?

Answer (score 4):

Take $$f_n (t) =\begin{cases} 0 \mbox{ if } a\leq t \leq \frac{a+b}{2} \\ \frac{2n}{b-a} t +\frac{n(a+b)}{a-b} \mbox{ if } \frac{a+b}{2}<t\leq \frac{a+b}{2} +\frac{b-a}{2n} \\ 1 \mbox{ if }\frac{a+b}{2} +\frac{b-a}{2n}<t\leq b \end{cases}$$ then $f_n$ is Cauchy but has not limit.

Comment: FisiaiLusia, how to show that this sequence is Cauchy but not convergent? Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

Let $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and take $x_n(t)=t^n.$ Then $d(x_n,x_m)$ is $|1/(n+1)-1/(m+1)| \to 0$ as $n,m \to \infty,$ yet the sequence  $x_n(t)$ approaches the function which is $0$ on $[0,1)$ and $1$ at $1.$

As pointed out by Ricky Demer in a comment, this example converges in the $d$ metric to the zero function. But it can be adjusted to work: Let $[a,b]=[0,2]$ and $x_n(t)=t^n$ if $0 \le t \le 1$ and $2-(2-t)^n$ for $1 < t \le 2.$ Then $x_n$ is Cauchy but does not converge in the $d$ metric to a continuous function.

Comment: coffeemath, how do we know that this sequence converges to a fucntion that is $0$ in $[0,1)$ and $1$ at $t=1$? Intuitively it is clear, but can you please show this rigorously?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud Just added a "sketch" of the statement about the limit function.

Comment: Let $\mathbf{0}$ be the zero function. $\;\;\;$ For all positive integers $n$, $\: d(x_n,\mathbf{0}) = \frac1{n+1} < \frac1n \;$. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer I see your point. My example only gets a series of functions with pointwise limit noncontinuous, however in the metric space $(X,d)$ it has the limit $0$. I'll delete for now, maybe re-do if an easy adjustment works.

Comment: @RickyDemer I'd appreciate it if you checked my adjusted function sequence just added, I think it works.

Comment: That seems to work. $\;$